# Test specific models in Django

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models, django-testing

Is it possible to have a set of models just for testing purposes? The idea is that I've written an app that contains some helper abstract model HelperBase. Now I'd like to provide some models that would inherit from it in order to test it, say DerivedTest1, DerivedTest2. However I wouldn't really like those test models to appear in the production database in the end. I just want their tables to be constructed in the test database. Is it possible and if so - how to do it? I've already tried creating models in the `tests.py` file but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502916/django-how-to-create-a-model-dynamically-just-for-testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try creating a whole new app that you only use on your development server.

E.g., if your app is called `myapp` you would call your testing app `myapp_test`.

Then in `myapp_test`'s `models.py` you would `from myapp import models` and then subclass your models in there.

Then in your `settings.py` you either just try and remember to comment out the `myapp_test` application from `INSTALLED_APPS` when deploying to your production server. Or you can use the `local_settings.py` methodology to only have the `myapp_test` included in `INSTALLED_APPS` on your test machine.