# How to test a custom field in Django 1.11.1

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I've create a custom field in Django

```py
class MyField(models.CharField):
    description = "My awesome field"

    # ...
```

I want to create a unit-test in which I make a temporary/ephemeral model that uses the field. My goal is to test that the functions like `to_python`, `from_db_value`, and `validate`, are implemented correctly from the view of an actual Model.

I also don't want to have the Model included in the production database. I've looked up a few different means of doing this and they **do not** work:

- https://www.kurup.org/blog/2014/07/21/django-test-models
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/503435/2097917
- https://blog.bixly.com/bixly-how-to-dynamically-adding-models-for-testing-in-django
- http://www.akshayshah.org/post/testing-django-fields/

These all seem to be outdated. I would like to  be able to define the model within an `tests.py` file (i.e. `projectroot/myapp/tests.py`) and somehow have the `setUp` add the model to the database:

```py
class MyModelTest(models.Model):
    myField = MyField()

class MyFieldTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp():
        # ... do something funky to create the table

    def test_foo(self):
        myModel = MyModel.objects.create(myField="something")
        self.assertEqual(myModel.myField, "something")
```

Does anyone have a good idea on how I could approach this?

Comment: I'm wondering if I could make a migration (in code) and apply that (in code), which will apply the migration to the test database during `./manage.py test`?

Comment: I've reverted to just testing that the field functions are implemented properly: `deconstruct()`, `to_python()`, `value_to_string()`, `from_db_value()`, and `get_prep_value()`. It seems that creating a migration was easy, but applying the migration in code is likely unsupported at the moment; based upon the code in `./manage.py migrate`. Unless somebody knows extra?